# Automation anywhere - the scheduled task is not displayed in the dashboard when it is running

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

When a task is executed and my dashboard is checked, the task does not appear, it appears only if it fails.
Also if I change my time zone, when loading my control room, some elements do not appear.
Has something similar happened to you?

Comment: Are you scheduling the task from the client or the Control Room?